# What am I doing wrong with my For loop in java?

Tags: java, loops, object, for-loop, return

I have been looking around for some answers to this question and I just can't seem to figure it out. I think that the issue seems to be with the 'scope' of my code but I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I could really use some help. I'm very new to Java.

**My goal**

1. Test to see if an object already exists in an array before adding it.
2. If the object already exists in the array, return null.
3. If it doesn't exist in the array, create it and then return it.

**The Code**

```
    public Business addBusiness(String person, String business, String location) {
    int id = 0;

    for (Business business : businesses ) {
        if (business.getPerson().equals(person)) {
            if (business.getBusiness().equals(business)) {
                if (business.getLocation().equals(location)) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Business newBusiness = new Business(person, business, location, id);
    return newBusiness;
}
```

**What happens when I run it**

When I run the code it will just happily create object after object with the same details. This leads me to believe that there is a problem with my logic. I was expecting that when it returned null, that would be the end of it.

I would appreciate any tips you can give me on solving this problem.

**EDIT: The 'Business' class**

```
public class Business {     
// Attributes //
private String person, business, location;
private int id;

// Constructor //

public Business(String person, String business, String location, int id) {
    this.person = person;
    this.business = business;
    this.location = location;
    this.id = id;
}

// Getters //

public String getPerson() {
    return person;
}

public String getBusiness() {
    return business;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
}
```

Comment: is **businesses** is arraylist or what?

Comment: what does `business.getPerson()` , `business.getBusiness()` and `business.getLocation()` return?

Comment: I have an array of business objects, when a business is created it gets given a person a business and a location.

getPerson returns a String

getBusiness returns a String

getLocation returns a String

They're the 'getter' methods for my business object. I'm trying to say "Look through the objects in the array and check to see if a person with that name already exists. If it does, check to see if a business with that name already exists. If it does, check to see if that location already exists." -- If all the information matches, then the business must already exist in the array.

Comment: Please add code for Business class.

Comment: Implement an equals method in your `Business` class. This will make your code cleaner.

Comment: It seems one of the if-statements in your for-loop is being evaluated to `false`. This might happen if there is difference in the case of the strings you are trying to compare. For e.g. the `equals` method will return false if you are trying to compare *Ross* and *ross*. Although they are same but the first string is camel-case and the second string is lowercase. Try using `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals` and see if it works

Comment: Also, replace the variable name `business` with something like `name` or something of the like.

Comment: Yes, I have an array list - businesses is an array list.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @Harry - I gave this a shot but it didnt' seem to solve the problem. Martijn I gave that a shot too and it still didn't help. No idea how I've butchered this so badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay -- so I think that I figured it out. Thank you so much to everyone for your help on this matter.

```
public Business addBusiness(String person, String business, String location) 
{
int id = 0;

for (Business business : businesses ) {
    if (business.getPerson().equals(person)) {
        if (business.getBusiness().equals(business)) {
            if (business.getLocation().equals(location)) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
Business newBusiness = new Business(person, business, location, id);
return newBusiness;
}
```

The issue was caused because I never actually added my newBusiness object into the array once it was created. So every time it ran it would never match an existing entry because there were no entries in the array.

The correct code should be something like:

```
public Business addBusiness(String person, String business, String location) 
{
int id = 0;

for (Business b : businesses ) {
    if (b.getPerson().equals(person)) {
        if (b.getBusiness().equals(business)) {
            if (b.getLocation().equals(location)) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
Business newBusiness = new Business(person, business, location, id);
b.add(newBusiness); // This was the missing line, now it seems to work fine.
return newBusiness;
}
```

Clearly, I still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public Business addBusiness(String person, String business, String location) 
{
    int id = 0;

    for (Business b : businesses ) {
        if (b.getPerson().equals(person)) {
            if (b.getBusiness().equals(business)) {
                if (b.getLocation().equals(location)) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Business newBusiness = new Business(person, business, location, id);
    return newBusiness;
}
```

You were masking the parameter `business` from the function's signature with the object you're iterating over in the loop. Renaming this to `b` avoids the issue.

Comment: But what is the difference between them?

Comment: Business business is replaced with Business b in this. xD

Comment: addBusiness(..) has a String param business and your for loop is creating a Business business....!!!!

So you got business object sure... not sure if that was type String or Business...

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve the issue. It continues to just keep creating new objects. Thank you for taking the time to help me find the answer, though!

Comment: Good you found a solution :)
The requirement in the original question "If it doesn't exist in the array, create it and then return it." was confusing to the fact that the object was supposed to be created, added to the array and then returned.

Happy coding :)